# A very complicated F1 administrative processing issue. What are my chances if I reapply (or apply for any other country's student visa in the future)?

Tags: usa, visa, student-visa, refusal, application-status

Greetings from Turkey;

I got a fully funded PhD offer from Illinois Institute of Technology on last April. I applied for an F1 visa to enroll in for Fall 2016 semester. Even though I got an approval on my interview, my application status remained under administrative processing for almost six months. I had to defer my admission twice, regardless of my efforts and the university's efforts to contact the embassy several times, since they were extremely indifferent and unhelpful. I regularly reminded them of my case and received the same generic answer. Also, I contacted an immigration attorney, who reached out the US Department of State and they told him that they will enquire with the US embassy in Turkey and that I should contact them as well. I did that again, and still got the same answer (that I have to wait and wait). Finally I sent them two letters, one from my supervisor who clearly pointed out the focus of his research (that he wasn't making explosives or biological weapons) and why he needs me, and one from the international office of the university. This time, they told me that I shouldn't have sent them those documents, because I wasn't asked to. This made me think that my case was lost or ignored forever.

At the end, I got really upset and sent the embassy a veeeeery long e-mail that contained literal sentences like "I can't take this anymore", "WHAT COULD I HAVE EVER DONE TO DESERVE THIS?" and "Even if I get cancer and the only cure is in the US, I will never set foot in your country" (I wasn't drunk or high). At the end of the e-mail I requested the withdrawal of my application, which they instantly agreed to like they had been waiting for me to give up already. I am not proud of what I did, but what is done cannot be undone.

My supervisor is trying very hard to help me and he is the coolest person on earth. So, I don't want to let this chance slip away. My question is, what would happen if I tried to apply at the same embassy. %100 administrative processing again? refusal for life? Should I apply for this visa at a different country with a valid excuse?

I know that I may never enter the US for my entire life, so I started applying to schools in other countries, but how would this thing affect my chances of getting a student visa from any other country in the future, especially the FVEY countries? I am worried about the fact that some countries have shared intelligence database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before giving up on the Illinois opportunity, I suggest contacting their international student support people. Apologize for sending an intemperate e-mail to the embassy, and ask their advice. They may be able to give you a better reading on whether it is worth trying USA again.

Comment: Why would application for the same US visa but through a US Embassy in another country help? Surely, it might make matters worse.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked two questions: what might happen should you reapply for a visa, and will information about your first application be shared with other countries.

No one can predict what will happen. The best suggestion is to keep it simple and behave. Even in your question, you've continued your critique. Remove hot words, don't interfere in the process or harass or bully or annoy. As you are painfully aware, none of that is helpful or productive.

To the second question, you did not get a refusal, you withdrew your application which keeps your record clean. While your e-tantrum may be out there, it is highly unlikely that it has been, or will be shared with the intelligence community.

For a better [overview, I'll defer to the expertise of @GayotFow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83130/do-embassies-know-about-visa-refusal-in-other-countries/83137#83137):

> The US and the UK are connected by the "Five Eyes Treaty" and the UK and Ireland are connected by the 2011 Agreement. The amount and type of data that gets flushed through these connections is indeterminate; the various governments do not make that information public.